# 'OR' operator in XPath predicate?

Tags: xpath, rss, atom-feed

What is the [XPath](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/) expression to select `<link>` elements with `type="application/rss+xml"` **OR** `type="application/atom+xml"` (RSS and Atom feeds)

- `link[@rel='alternate'][@type='application/rss+xml']` selects RSS feeds
- `link[@rel='alternate'][@type='application/atom+xml']` selects Atom feeds

But what is the single XPath expression for selecting them both?

Thank you.

Answer (score 54, accepted):

use:

```
link[@rel='alternate'][@type='application/rss+xml' or @type='application/atom+xml']
```

see http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#NT-OrExpr

You could also use union to accomplish this

```
link[@rel='alternate'][@type='application/rss+xml']|link[@rel='alternate'][@type='application/atom+xml']
```

but `or` will do.

Answer (score 12):

if you want to get fancy and use XPath 2.0, it is more elegant (but potentially confusing, depending who might be reading the code) to write it like this:

```
link[@rel='alternate'][@type = ('application/rss+xml', 'application/atom+xml')]
```

the reason for this is that XPath 2.0 redefines '=' to apply to sequences, which means that the above comparison returns true if there is one match when comparing items from the left-hand sequence with comparing items from the right-hand sequence. this can be very useful if the list of things you want to compare with is dynamic.