# XPath in Python xml.ElementTree: OR:ing on attribute value

Tags: python, xml

I want to select elements based on an  a range of attribute values. I have this without the 'or' functionality:

```
elem = root.iterfind('.//container/image/[name="foo"]..')
```

I would like something in the line of:

```
elem = root.iterfind('.//container/image/[name="foo" OR name="bar"]..')
```

How can this be acheived?

Comment: Does this answer your question? ['OR' operator in XPath predicate?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2211693/or-operator-in-xpath-predicate)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not in xpath in ElementTree (because of [limited xpath support](https://docs.python.org/3/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#xpath-support)).

However, you could use [lxml](https://lxml.de/xpathxslt.html)...

```py
elem = root.xpath('.//container/image[name="foo" or name="bar"]')
```

That selects `image` elements that have a child `name` element with the value `foo` or `bar`. I wasn't sure what you were trying to select because the predicate wasn't preceded by an element name.

Or if you were using something that supported XPath 2.0 (like the [python module](https://www.saxonica.com/saxon-c/doc/html/saxonc.html) of [Saxon/C](https://www.saxonica.com/saxon-c/documentation/index.html)) you could test against a sequence of values...

```py
elems = xpathproc.evaluate('.//container/image[name=("foo","bar")]')
```